# MFMailComposeViewController dismiss issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, email, uiviewcontroller

I am experiencing a strange issue with the MFMailComposeViewController. I have been working with the MFMailComposeViewController in the past without any problems but now I can't figure out what's wrong this time and therefore I would like your help.

In my application I have multiple UIViewControllers where the one named MainViewController is a ViewController container where i implemented a left slide menu. In the MainViewController i added a UINavigationController as well. The UINavigationController is allocated and afterwards added to MainViewController like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.navigationController];
[self.centerView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The above work perfectly fine and I can use the navigation controller to push and pop other UIViewControllers.
In the left menu I got different buttons, and one of them is named "About". When it is pressed the following code is executed:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[AboutViewController sharedViewController]];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:array animated:NO];
```

In AboutViewController i got some buttons where one of them is "Send feedback". The "Send feedback" button executes the following code:

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"feedback@test.com"], nil]; 
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients]; 
    [mailer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Feedback"]];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Which is also working. The AboutViewController implements the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and its method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            //NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            //NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            //NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            //NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            //NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And its here I get the headache. I call the

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

as I did in previous apps where it worked without any problems. But in this case the MFMailComposeViewController is not being dismissed and the "Cancel" and "Send" buttons become inactive. I tried to implement a NSLog in the dismiss completion block but it is never being called.

I googled for hours now and can't find a way to solve this problem. I hope you can help me solve this strange issue. If you need more information just ask.

Thanks in advance.
- Sebastian

Comment: you getting the problem for your child view controller

Comment: you have to resize your child view

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? In the allocation of the navigation controller I do the following:
`self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, [Utilities screenHeight] - 44);
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59607/discussion-between-sebastian-sondergaard-and-bhaskar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I found out that one of the threads that the MainViewController managed started an endless loop in main thread when the MainViewController should become visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open mail controller into parent viewcontroller. To do this you have to use delegate.
Call The MFMailComposeViewController in your parentclass and passed value by custom delegate

Comment: So in the MainViewController? I tried to move the code there but the MFMailComposeViewController is still not dismissing.

Comment: you can tap the cancel button?

Comment: Maybe I were unclear i my question. I'm able to press the cancel button which brings up the actionsheet. When I press delete draft or save draft the MFMailComposeViewController is not dismissing. It's not dismissing when the send button is pressed as well.

Comment: i want to say - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error method is call or not?

Comment: It looks like it is kind of freezing in the dismiss call because I added a NSLog below it and it is never being executed.

Comment: do you excute line by line?